# Importing processing.js game to google play

Tags: processing.js

I really wanna learn processing.js at Khanacademy, but im not sure if i can import a game made with processing.js and javascript to Google play or appstore. Is there anyone who can give me some answers about this specific topic?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty huge question, so it's not very fitting for Stack Overflow. But I'll try to answer in general terms.

First off, please try to understand the difference between a JavaScript application, an Android app, and an iPhone app.

Processing.js can generate a JavaScript app, which you can embed in a website. You can then visit that site in a mobile browser, but it's not an app you can upload to an app store.

You could create an Android or iPhone app that used something like a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) component to display the website just like a browser would.

Or you could try to port your Processing sketch over to a native app. Processing can be deployed to Android using [Processing for Android](https://github.com/processing/processing-android/wiki), but I'm not sure about iOS.

In the end I really wouldn't worry about whether you can upload a Processing sketch to the app store. Get something working first. Learn the basics. Don't worry about deployment until you understand what's going on.

Comment: I now have basic overview about what i can do. Thanks for ansswering my question.